# Excel - Sum values of column A if the values of column B are in column D. How do I do that?

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I have a table where in column A I have the units bought, in column B I have the client IDs and in column D I have a list of clients IDs.

What I need to do is sum the units bought just of the clients that appear in column D. So in the table below it should just sum 2 and 3 as 31 and 1 are the only IDs that appear in column D.

Is there any way to do it with =SUMPRODUCT() or any build-it functions (which I'd prefer)? Or do I need to write a function in VBA?

[image]

EDIT: is there any way to do it in one cell?

Comment: When you say '"to do it in one cell", would that mean to do it in, let us say, E2? In such a case, I would propose to apply a list validation to E1, selecting like list the range "D2:D9". And putting a formula in E2 using `SumIf`function. All that can be also automate in VBA... I mean, to create validation and programmatically write the necessary formula...

Answer (score 0):

So try this using sumif():

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$9,D2,$A$2:$A$9)
```

based on your data, I have an image but it won't load yet...

[image]

If you want the total sum from all those ID's then this works:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(B2:B9,D2:D7,A2:A9))
```

Has to be entered as an array formula (ctrl+shift+enter)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I could already do it like this, but I'd need to do it in one single cell, is it possible?

Comment: @Lorenzo in column D you use more than one cell for the client id’s so either you are asking for something else or I did not understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The next piece of code will create a validation to cell E1, using a list (collecting values from D:D column, and write a formula (in E2) able to calculate the summarized values of the above (E1) selected 'Client ID':

```
Sub ExtractSumIfInaCell()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
  Set sh = ActiveSheet

  With sh.Range("E1").Validation
        .Delete
        .aDD Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=" & sh.Range("D2:D" & sh.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).address
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
  End With
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  sh.Range("E2").Formula = "=SUMIF(B2:B" & lastRow & ",E1,A2:A" & lastRow & ")"
End Sub
```

So, after running the code, you must only select a 'Client ID' from the E1 validation drop down and the necessary amount will be calculated in E2...

Comment: So will this work for clients 31 & 1 or the range of id’s you gave in column d?

Answer (score 0):

try this `=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A9*(B2:B9=TRANSPOSE(D2:D9)))`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sum theUnits Bought column multiplied by a vector that return 1/0 for Client ID found

```
=SUM($A$2:$A$9*IFERROR(MATCH($B$2:$B$9,$D$2:$D$9,0)>0,0))
```